# While uploading csv file in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

While I am uploading a csv file using php coding in MySQL ,all rows and columns were inserting .I have 670 data in it but it is inserting 1000 rows,I want only 670 rows to be added

Comment: put your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code hope this help you

```
  $count=0;
  while(($data = fgetcsv($inputfp, 4096, ',')) !== FALSE) {
    if($count==670)  Break; 
    else{
    //your inserting code here
    }
    $count++;
   }
```